# Partial view not refreshing after Jquery delete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 application, partial view is not refreshing after delete operation. My partial view is as below

```
@model IEnumerable<SFRS.DataMarketPlace.Data.Dataset_Files>
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;

@{ int datasetId = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
datasetId = item.DatasetID;

<div class="FileLinkBox clearfix)">
    <a class="FileLink FileLinkColor" href="@Href("/files")/dataset/@item.FilePath">@item.FilePath</a>
</div>
<div class="deleteFileLink"><a class="removeFile" href="#" data-id="@item.ID">(Delete File)</a>  </div>
}
```

```
 @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true, includeFormTag:  false,  addText: " Add more files")
<a href="#" onclick="removeFile(); return false;">Remove last file</a>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('.removeFile').click(function () {
    var fileid = $(this).attr('data-id');             
    var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '@Url.Action("RemoveDatasetFile", "Dataset")',
            data: { id: fileid, datasetId: @datasetId }

        })
            .success(function(result) {
            })
            .error(function(xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    }    

});
```

The delete operation does work and when I refresh the page I do see the file deleted. And see below how I call this partial view from the main view

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   @Html.Partial("_DatasetFiles", @Model.Dataset_Files)
</div>
```

The method which handles this requests is as below

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual PartialViewResult RemoveDatasetFile(int id,int datasetId)
    {
       this.UnitOfWork.DatasetRepository.RemoveDatasetFileByDatasetIdAndId(id,datasetId);
       this.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        var revisedDatasetFiles = this.UnitOfWork.DatasetRepository.GetDatasetFilesByDatasetId(datasetId);
        return PartialView("_DatasetFiles", revisedDatasetFiles);
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. You are triggering an AJAX request to delete the file and returning a refreshed view from there. But you are not doing anyting in Success method of AJAX callback. Here you should write code which will render the returned response HTML to the target DIV.

Comment: As @KD suggest, if you don't return anything on the success callback of the ajax method, nothing will happen. Try to put a breakpoing in the RemoveDatasetFile PartialViewResult. If the operation succeeded, in the success callback you should call your partialview again (I preder RenderAction, instead of Partial because you can handle other actions and then return the partialview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide some identifier to your DIV container first.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 target">
   @Html.Partial("_DatasetFiles", @Model.Dataset_Files)
</div>
```

And then you should handle the response sent from server in following manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.removeFile').click(function () {
    var fileid = $(this).attr('data-id');             
    var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '@Url.Action("RemoveDatasetFile", "Dataset")',
            data: { id: fileid, datasetId: @datasetId }

        })
            .success(function(result) {
                // Here you should have a code to render the server response to your target div
                $(".target").html(result);
            })
            .error(function(xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    }    

});
```

Comment: Perfect K D. I should have noticed it but thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Changes to make:

1)

This line could be messing you up

```
var fileid = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

it should read

```
var fileid = $(this).data('id');
```

When you use data-* attributes, you can access them through .data() 
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Also, always open up your browser developer tools when debugging, you can usually see errors like this in the "Console" tab

2)

Like the answer above me, you should be replacing the html of the element in your .success function

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '@Url.Action("RemoveDatasetFile", "Dataset")',
        data: { id: fileid, datasetId: @datasetId }
    })
    .success(function(result) {
        $(".target").html(result); // Replace the contents of this element with the result returned from your controller
    })
    .error(function(xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
});
```

Comment: no errors in console and I have checked the fileid using alert and the value is correct. thanks

Comment: When debugging, where does the error occur? (If at all)

Comment: I don't see any errors except this view won't refresh itself

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your dataset's action "RemoveDatasetFile". If your path is right, you should be able to debug there when you call your ajax function

Comment: I have added my controller method above and it works as expected. First two lines remove the entry from the database. The next two lines pull the new entries and should refresh the partial view. But I don't know what I m missing here